# php - understanding this->request->post

Tags: php, html, post, get

I'm studying someone else's code in order to learn php,html and something I don't understand is this:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['eid'])) {
        $eid = $this->request->post['eid'];
    } else {
        $eid = '0';
    }
```

How exaclty is the value of the field eid passed to the php file that just opened and  how can I use this mechanism to pass values to other files? And secondary..what is different when get is used instead of post at the same statement?

Comment: Frameworks, it's useful to name them when asking about them. Still, the question is essentially about [http request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) (and that topic is hardly coverable by a single SO answer).

Comment: I would like to apologize to the downvoters for not being born with infitive programming knowledge and for attempting to learn more by reaching out to a global helping community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `->` *arrow* operator is used to get variables and functions that belong to an object.

In this case, `$this` is an object and you're getting the varible `request` from that object. That variable contains another object which has a variable `post`. That variable is an array and you're getting the value with index *"eid"* from that array using `post['eid']`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->request->post['eid'] is same as $_POST["eid"] in simple words.
```

`$this->request->post['eid']` is used in the frameworks. `$_POST` is the array of values which you get on form submission.